# How do I sort a range of filters and functions?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to sort a range that is populated by a filter and various functions. Whenever I try and apply a "filter" (the upside down triangle in the toolbar) and try and sort names or numbers from low to high it just unsorts itself after a second or so.

[image]

An example image of the ranges I would like to sort, whenever I try they just unsort themselves.

How do you sort ranges that are populated by a Filter(),  Sort(), or Importrange() type of function?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a function that outputs an array, you are going to get that array. Trying to sort the output won't do any good: the function was asked to produce a certain array, and so it does.

But you can use another [`sort`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) to produce output sorted in a desired way. If you will need multiple ways of sorting, this can be arranged using data validation and [`match`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) function.

Suppose your range to sort is in columns A-C, with these headers.

```
+---+------+-------+--------+
|   |  A   |   B   |   C    |
+---+------+-------+--------+
| 1 | Name | Title | Salary |
+---+------+-------+--------+
```

I will set up a sortable version of this in columns E-F.

```
E1 ={A1:C1}
E2 =sort(A2:C, match(D2, A1:C1, 0), true)
```

The cell D1 would have text "Sort by:" and cell D2 have Data Validation of the type "Value from a range", the range being A1:C1.

Result:

- a user selects the column to sort by in cell D2 (using a dropdown provided by data validation)
- `match` finds the number of this column
- `sort` sorts by it, with the sorted array appearing in columns E-F.